# Thread-safely initializing a pointer just once

Tags: c, multithreading, initialization

I'm writing a library function, say, `count_char(const char *str, int len, char ch)` that detects the supported SIMD extensions of the CPU it's running on and dispatches the call to, say, an AVX2- or SSE4.2-optimized version. Since I'd like to avoid the penalty of doing a couple of `cpuid` instructions per each call, I'm trying to do this just once the first time the function is called (which might be called by different threads simultaneously).

In C++ land I'd just do something like

```
int count_char(const char *str, int len, char ch) {
    static const auto fun_ptr = select_simd_function();
    return (*fun_ptr)(str, len, ch);
}
```

and rely on C++ semantics of `static` to guarantee that it's called exactly once without any race conditions. But what's the best way to do this in pure C?

This is what I've come up with:

1. Using atomic variables (that are also present in C) — rather error-prone and a bit harder to maintain.
2. Using `pthread_once` — not sure about what overhead it has, plus it might give headache on Windows.
3. Forcing the library user to call another library function to initialize the pointer — in short, it won't work in my case since this is actually C bits of a library for another language.
4. Aligning the pointer by 8 bytes and relying on x86 word-sized accesses being atomic — unportable to other architectures (shall I later implement some PowerPC or ARM-specific SIMD versions, say), technically UB (at least in C++).
5. Using thread-local storage and marking `fun_ptr` as `thread_local` and then doing something like

```
    static thread_local fun_ptr_t fun_ptr = NULL;
    if (!fun_ptr) {
        fun_ptr = select_simd_function();
    }
    return (*fun_ptr)(str, len, ch);
```

The upside is that the code is very clear and apparently correct, but I'm not sure about the performance implications of TLS, plus every thread will have to call `select_simd_function()` once (but that's probably not a big deal).

For me personally, (5) is the winner so far, followed closely by (1) (I'd probably even go with (1) if it weren't somebody else's very foundational library and I didn't want to embarrass myself with a likely faulty implementation).

So, what'd be the best option? Did I miss anything else?

Comment: Have you examined using initializer functions, such as with GCC's `__attribute__((constructor))`?  You'd probably need some `#ifdef` constructs for different platforms, and all your platforms would need to support something similar.

Comment: Yep, the issue with it is that I didn't find any good analog for clang which I definitely need to support, and I'm also not sure about other compilers out there that I can't even get my hands on.

Comment: What *is* the actual "penalty" of just ... executing a couple of `cpuid` instructions per call?

Comment: When you just go the naive route of version 5 without `thread_local`, what can possibly happen? The result of `select_simd_function()` is the same in all threads, so even with a race condition and non-atomic writing to `fun_ptr`, probably no corruption could happen

Comment: @MikeRobinson Not doing anything fancy is also an option, but, say, Ivy Bridge has `cpuid` latency of up to 340 cycles, which gives up to a thousand cycles for the dispatching function — that's enough to count chars in a string of a few kilobytes by a ballpark estimate. @Ctx in that case I'm more worried about fancy optimizations the compiler can make that I can't think of — I've been bitten by UBs more than I'd like to. For instance, what happens if there's a partial write in one thread, the other thread sees the partial write so `if (!fun_ptr)` doesn't fire, but `fun_ptr` is invalid?

Comment: @0xd34df00d Well, if you see it this way, I would vote for your version 5. Good point, btw. You could do `static int valid = 0; static funptr_t funptr = NULL; if (!valid) { funptr = select_simd_function(); valid = 1; }` to mitigate this though.

Comment: My concern, 0xd, is that some other strategy might take longer than the instruction.

Comment: A common way to handle things like this is to do them when the program is first starting-up and before it launches any threads.

Comment: @0xd34df00d `__attribute__((constructor))` is not on [the list of GCC extensions that clang doesn't support](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#gcc-extensions-not-implemented-yet), so clang at least should support it.

Comment: Re, "thread local storage" You might want to look under the hood... see what happens when you access or assign a thread-local variable, before declaring it to be your magic bullet.

Comment: @SolomonSlow I should've done that in the first place! It does not look particularly awful to me though: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/RzqFQM

Comment: @Ctx that would be UB due to a data race if there are multiple threads, the flag variable should be an atomic type. And even if doing that, the function may be executed twice if another thread runs the same test before `valid=1` was applied (causing a data race on `funptr`, which could end up with a torn write or anything else). Functions like `pthread_once` or standard library `call_once` handle all these possibilities

Comment: @Ctx saying "even if there's a race condition probably nothing will go wrong" is asking for trouble imho

Comment: On the portability issue, I see by googling that there are a few third party implementations of C11 threads for MSVC  , or you could even just pick out the implementation of `call_once` which is a couple of Windows API calls.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can use C11, this would work (assuming your implementation supports threads - [it's an optional feature](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.26.1p2)):

```
#include <threads.h>

static fun_ptr_t fun_ptr = NULL;

static void init_fun_ptr( void )
{
    fun_ptr = select_simd_function();
}

fun_ptr_t get_simd_function( void )
{
    static once_flag flag = ONCE_FLAG_INIT;

    call_once( &flag, init_fun_ptr);

    return ( fun_ptr );
}
```

Of course, you mentioned Windows.  I doubt MSVC supports this.

Comment: FYI: "threads.h" is an **optional** C11 feature, might not always be available.

Comment: I somehow missed that C11 has `call_once` too, thank you!

Comment: @Myst Updated to reflect the optional nature of thread support.